# dd/MM/yyyy Date Format to Monthname day,Year Java Android

Tags: java, date

First i have a java Date object lets say

```
Date firstdate;            // its initialized and equal to some date dont worry
```

with using this code i convert it to dd/MM/yyyy  format

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                date.setText(sdf.format(firstdate));
```

But since sdf.format is returning to a string,after formating 1 time i cant format it again to my desired Monthname day,Year format  before displaying to user.

i mean if `sdf.format(firstdate)` returns "01/01/2000" string,i would like to convert this to January 1,2000   and then display it to user.

Comment: Why do you use "dd/MM/yyyy" is that's not the format you need? Anyway, you can turn a string back to date with parse() method. See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: You need a completely different format object if you expect `format()` method to produce anything different

Comment: I recommend `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG).withLocale(Locale.US);` since your requested format agrees with this. Do take advantage. And use `LocalDate` for your date. How to use on Android? See [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

Answer (score 1):

First get the `String` and convert to a `Date`:

```
String s = date.getText();  // e.g. "01/01/2000"
Date d = sdf.parse(s);      // parse the String to get a Date object
```

Then you need a second `SimpleDateFormat` to convert the `Date` to the desired `String`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy");
s = sdf2.format(d);         // "January 1, 2000"
```